# Notepad++ Regex to match a string

Tags: regex, notepad++

What is the best way possible to match something based on the place of the string?

For example: 
`Name - Date - OtherName, DiffrentName - ID - RandomText1 - RandomText2`

I want a regex the will do something like: select the part between ( - ) number2 and ( - ) number3. so it'll select `OtherName, DiffrentName`

Or select the part between ( - ) number4 and ( - ) number5 .so it'll select `RandomText1`

My very stupid and ugly solution was something like this: `^.*( -)(.*)( - ).*( - ).*( - )` 
then I'll replace with \2 so I'll get the desired result

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: *What is the best way possible* implies you know at least an average way.

Comment: My very stupid and ugly solution was something like this: ^.*( -)(.*)( - ).*( - ).*( - ) then I'll replace with \2 so I'll get the desired result

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/wQ5m1o/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match the first, second etc.. you might use a quantifier like `{n}` where n is the number of times to set the repetition of repeating one or more word characters `\w+` followed by a dash `-` and a whitespace.

Then use `\K` to reset the starting point of the reported match and match  NOT a dash `[^-]+` one or more times with a positive lookahead that asserts what follows is a whitespace and a dash OR the end of the line `$`.

[`^(?:[\w, ]+- ){2}\K[^-]+(?= -|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/B73G0r/1)